# Why do we have two equally used terms for "toe"?

Tags: etymology, gender, noun

There are two translations for `toe` that both are equally used. Both are pronounced almost the same but they have a different gender:

> der Zeh, *m*
>
> die Zehe, *f*

What is the origin of this difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know why there are two forms of this word. According to Wictionary people from northern Germany tend to use `Zeh` while `Zehe` is more common in central and southern regions.

- http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zehe
- http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zeh

There is a difference when referring to "Knoblauch" (garlic) though. You'll have to use "Zehe": die Knoblauchzehe ("clove of garlic").

Comment: In the (admittedly obscure, southern ;) ) dialect I speak, only "Zeh" is used, pronounced as "der Zeach". It's similar to "Butter": *m* in parts of South Germany/Austria and *f* in the rest of the world. ;)

Comment: It's *le beurre, m* in France - that's why the once french occupied south of Germany still uses it.

Comment: @Takkat Interesting, but do you have a reference for this? I doubt it because the word butter surely predates any french occupation. Or am I wrong?

Comment: sorry no reference but "Butter" stems from Latin *butyrum* (neuter to further complicate things).

Comment: Berlin has - I think - lots of french influences, but Butter is feminine here.

Answer (score 4):

It happens more often that two words with this difference in morphology and gender exist, even more so in regional dialects, usually the longer word is the more formally correct word.

(I think that this is also the reason that French loanwords ending in -age are female because they are felt to be an -e expansion of the male French prononciation).

Examples:

> der Schaumspitz, die Spitze
>
> der Dreizack, die Zacke
>
> der Heuschreck, die Heuschrecke
>
> der Zeck, die Zecke

In the first two cases, the shorter male version is mostly used in composita, so I gave them as example, in the other two examples, the male vesion are regional variants.

Answer (score 3):

It's a regional difference. "der Zeh" is used in the Northern regions of Germany, whereas "die Zehe" is used in the Southern regions.

Both are correct, and there is no difference in meaning. Just an example about the inconsistency of a living language.

My Duden (1986 -- I know!!) allows both:

> Zehe, die; -, -n, (auch:) Zeh, der;
>   -s, -en; die kleine, große Zehe, der kleine, große Zeh

Comment: Interesting! Beware that "Zehe" is used for garlic pieces (as splattne mentioned already), so you might get some laughs in the north for "Zehe". Also, I've never heard "Meine große Zehe" for "Mein großer Zeh", while "Meine kleine Zehe" sounds fine to me. Don't come from the south, though.

Comment: Just describing, not committing :-) I was raised in the Rhine area and "Meine grosse Zehe" would never make it across my lips. "Meine kleine Zehe" neither. Lang lebe der Zeh!

Comment: I like to say "der Knoblauchzeh". But I also refer to pieces of an Orange as "eine Orangenzehe", because I don't know what they're called, and I like strange humor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take an educated guess:

[According to the Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zeh), *Zehe* comes from *zēhe* and *zēha*. Dropping of the final e is something that is not uncommon in many dialects (*Wehe* and *Weh*, *Gabe* and *Gab*). Why exactly *Zeh* permeated I don't know.